# Trying to find the actual name of an eastern european distilled beverage

Tags: alcohol, drinks, beverages

this is hopefully a simple question. I have had several friends from Eastern Europe, and they often visited with a bottle of a family-style distilled beverage. It is made with pretty much whatever fruits are available (I've had plum, prune, cherry, etc). The closest I can come with the pronunciation is "trweeka," but that is from memory so I could be slightly off. It would be found in the Ukraine, Czech Republic, Bulgaria, Moldova, Poland... those types of places. I am hoping someone may be familiar and know the proper name in Cyrillic and transliterated to English? I'd like to learn more about it.

Comment: Kvass perhaps? I've seen that in eastern europe, it seems to be used as a catch-all term in some areas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean [Tuica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A2uic%C4%83). This is a Romanian liquor, made from fruits. 
It is quite similar to Palinka, a Hungarian liquor with a protected name.

Comment: THIS IS IT! Thank you thank you thank you. I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

In the Czech Republic (and other countries around us) we have a drink made from fruits called ["slivovice"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slivovitz)

Comment: Awesome! I was hoping I could find someone local who could provide an answer. We just finished a bottle of rachya (again, based on phonetics and not spelling) from Macedonia, and it turned me on to some of the cool home distilled things coming out of that part of the world. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: You're welcome! The drink you're talking about now is rakia, not made in the Czech Republic under that name but great nevertheless:)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 'distilled', then in Poland it would be "bimber". But there's also a beverage made  by mixing a strong alcohol (spirit) with various fruits (or coffee ;) ) and leaving it for half a year or longer. This is called "nalewka"